# How can I multiply Percent(%) in R?

Tags: r

I want to write some code that include `x * %` in R.

This is my code:

```r
for(i in 1:8){
  a <- i*10%
  print(a)
}
```

But, my code didn't work.

How can I modify this code to check the result like 10%, 20%, 30%...

Comment: try `for(i in 1:8){ 
  a <- i*10  
  print(paste0(a,'%')) 
  }
`

Comment: Or vectorised way : `paste0(1:8 * 10, '%')`

Comment: It's the beauty of R that it works in vectors. So Ronak's suggestion is very good.  No need to do it with any loop

Answer (score 0):

The symbol percent (%) can only exist as a string while your loop variable i is an integer. As you have seen in other comments, append the string '%' when you print.

```
print( paste0( seq(1,8) * 10, "%"))
```